# Can i shorten this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-cleanup

I have around 20 buttons that view different type av boxes when clicked, so my JS code is really long. The function works perfect but im wondering if there is a way to shorten this code or make it more cleaner?

```
// Content lvl 1
function show(sel) {
  var el = $(sel);
  el.fadeToggle();
  $('.showmore-1').not(el).fadeOut("slow");
}

$('.showmore-1').hide();

$('#click-1a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1a');
});

$('#click-1b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-1b');
});

// Content lvl 2
function show(sel) {
  var el = $(sel);
  el.fadeToggle();
  $('.showmore-2').not(el).fadeOut("slow");
}

$('.showmore-2').hide();

$('#click-2a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-2a');
});

$('#click-2b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-2b');


// Content lvl 3
function show(sel) {
  var el = $(sel);
  el.fadeToggle();
  $('.showmore-3').not(el).fadeOut("slow");
}

$('.showmore-3').hide();

$('#click-3a').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-3a');
});

$('#click-3b').click(function () {
  show('#showmore-3b');
});
```

And this will continue to click 20 i maybe will do even more.

Comment: If code is working but you seek improvements then question should be posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sure, you could use as selector `'[id^="click-"]'` and get relevant number (or index), or use a class, or data-id, or use any relevant transversal method, or etc... You should post relevant HTML markup in order to get better solution but anyway this is SO offtopic question, so....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES

```
$("[id^=click]").click(function (e) { //match elements with ID's starting with "click"
    oldSelector =  e.target.id; //get the ID of the clicked element
    newSelector = oldSelector.replace("click", "showmore"); //replace string
    show(newSelector);    
});
```

Advantage is that the code keeps working if you add more or less buttons the same way. No need to update this code for it, nor the HTML itself.

Body as 1 liner:

```
$("[id^=click]").click(function (e) { 
    show(e.target.id.replace("click", "showmore"));    
});
```

Comment: while it is indeed shorter and (probably) fits this case, this would cause errors when you have an element `div#clicktarget`.

Comment: @DoXicK It would try to select `div#showmoretarget` which doesn't exist in the current dom probably? But you can check if the new selector has any matches of course. (or am I wrong?)

Comment: yeah you can of course check it. But the most transparent and maintainable way is what Niet proposed. Yours would work, no problems there, but it is very much tied to this use case.

Comment: @DoXicK Best way (better than mine or Niet's) would be using a selector using a surrounding div and the current element type. (for future visitors)

Comment: Have to agree with @DoXicK on this one, but I will point out that it won't actually cause errors - jQuery silently ignores the case where no elements match the selector, so it would fade out all the `.showmore` but not fade in anything. However, if there happens to actually be a `#showmoretarget` element then things start behaving unpredictably.

Comment: @Thomas not exactly. The code @NietTheDarkAbsol provided will let you do all of that by making the "data-for" value more specific: `<div class="clickable" data-for="#someelement .child .hidden">click me!</div>`. It's about as flexible and futureproof as you can get it.

Comment: Hi! Thats awesome can i just ask. Im making a 3 content-level FAQ exactly like this https://goo.gl/Z9LJ8s  so in my code i got 3 different type of class so lets say you have pressed on an button lvl 1, then on lvl 2 and then on lvl 3 and after that you change your mind you want to change the button on lvl 2 THEN only content from lvl 3 will be affeceted and not level 1. With this code i cant manage to fix it. I refreshed my code so u can see what i mean, i got access to CSS and HTML. Is also possible to make when you press a button it change color so u know what button u pressed?

Comment: @MerinRV in order to keep SO clean, could you ask this in a `new` question?

Comment: Yes sure but im not allowed to post anymore today :( im really in desperat of help :(

Answer (score 3):

If your HTML is editable, try something like this:

```
<button class="clickable" data-for="#showmore-1">Click</button>
```

Then your jQuery becomes:

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).on("click",".clickable",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        show(this.getAttribute("data-for"));
    });

    function show(sel) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var counter = 0; counter < 20; counter++)
{
  $('#click-' + counter).click(function () {
    var idCounter = $( this ).attr( "id" ).split( "-" )[1];
    show('#showmore-' + idCounter );
  });
}
```

or better yet, bind a click event to a class rather than on id

Comment: No, you need some closure here and anyway not really the shortest way.... (bis repetita)

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, got it (counter value would be wrong), corrected the logic now'

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are like:

```
<div id="click-1">click me</div>
```

make them like:

```
<div class="showing-trigger" data-target-id="showmore-1">click me</div>
```

and then your handlers could be:

```
$('.showing-trigger').on('click', function () {
    show('#' + $(this).data('target-id'));
});
```

Note that with this code your triggers can show a div with any id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var i=1,l=21; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){ // closure scopes off i so it's not at end of loop when Event occurs
    $('#click-'+i).click(function(){
      $('.showmore').fadeOut('slow', function(){ // fade showmore class out
        $('#showmore-'+i).show(); // show just the one you want
      });
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be shortened to this:

```
$("[id^= click]").click(function (e) { 
    oldSelector =  e.target.id; //get the ID of the clicked element
    newSelector = oldSelector.replace("click", "showmore"); 
    show(newSelector); 
});
```